# Return value for RESTful Batch Delete

Tags: rest, django-rest-framework

I have an API with a model that requires the ability to delete many models at once. As such, I've written a DELETE method on the List for that model. However it's possible that the user doesn't have permission to delete some of the models. Is there a pattern to indicate which models were deleted successfully and which weren't? My current approach is this:

```
class ModelList(APIView):

    def delete(self, request, format=None):

        models = MyModel.objects.all()

        models.filter(<some filtering>)

        response = []
        for m in models:

            if m.deletionForbidden:
                response.append("Forbidden")
            else:
                m.delete()
                response.append("No Content")

        return Response(response)
```

But this feels sort of messy/unintuitive. Is there a better way?

Comment: You can return an error object with the ids the server could not delete. Btw. it would be better to disable the checkbox by those, so you could spare this kind of work and refuse any attempt which contains non-removable items.

Comment: Might it make sense to do the delete as a single atomic operation across all the elements, return `204 NO CONTENT` if the transaction completed successfully and otherwise rollback/return `400 BAD REQUEST` if it failed?

Answer (score 0):

You can return 2 keys `'deleted'` and `'forbidden'` in the response.

`'deleted'` key contains the object ids which are deleted and the `'forbidden'` key contains the object ids which a user does not have permission to delete.

```
class ModelList(APIView):

    def delete(self, request, format=None):
        """
        This method performs bulk delete on objects for which a user has permission
        to delete. The response will contain 2 keys 'deleted' and 'forbidden'. These 
        will contain the ids deleted and the ids forbidden to delete.
        """        
        objs = MyModel.objects.filter(**filter_params) # list of objects to be deleted        
        ids_deleted = [] # contain the ids which are deleted
        ids_forbidden = [] # contain the ids which a user does not have permission to delete

        for obj in objs:
            if obj.deletionForbidden: # check if user has permission to delete the object
                ids_forbidden.append(obj.id) # append the id to the list              
            else:
                ids_deleted.append(obj.id) # append the id to list

        MyModel.objects.filter(id__in=ids_deleted).delete() # bulk delete all the objects

        return_dict = {
            'deleted': ids_deleted,
            'forbidden': ids_forbidden
        }

        return Response(return_dict, status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```